# Use of LookupAccountSidW

Tags: c++, winapi

LookupAccountSid is a function to retrieve the ACL (Access control list) of a file
Here's the [example code](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/secauthz/searching-for-a-sid-in-an-access-token-in-c--)
In the example, it uses of

```
   char lpName[MAX_NAME];
   char lpDomain[MAX_NAME];
```

. So it's supposed to be used in an Ascii project.

My project is unicode, so LookupAccountSid would be [LookupAccountSidW](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw).

```
BOOL LookupAccountSidW(
  LPCWSTR       lpSystemName,
  PSID          Sid,
  LPWSTR        Name,
  LPDWORD       cchName,
  LPWSTR        ReferencedDomainName,
  LPDWORD       cchReferencedDomainName,
  PSID_NAME_USE peUse
);
```

My question is for cchName,

> On input, specifies the **size, in TCHARs, of** the lpName buffer. If the
> function fails because the buffer is too small or if cchName is zero,
> cchName receives the required buffer size, including the terminating
> null character.

I have seen example code on somewhere (not MS offical site)

```
TCHAR bufName[MAX_PATH];
DWORD dwCbName = sizeof(bufName);
```

I'm suspicious of this `sizeof(bufName)`, or should it be `sizeof(bufName)/sizeof(TCHAR)`?

I'm not familiar with the expression of `the size, in TCHARs, of the lpName buffer`. If it would have been "size of the lpName buffer", `sizeof(bufName)` could be correct. But there is `in TCHARs` , it seems to be like count rather than size.

Comment: "*the size, in TCHARs*" That means the `TCHAR` count. Windows convention is to use `cch` for count of characters (whether narrow or wide), and `cb` for count of bytes. Different APIs require different counts, so the second snippet probably sets up the variable for an API that requires the *byte* count.

Comment: what sense use `LookupAccountSidW` when exist `LsaLookupSids[2]`

Answer (score 0):

```
BOOL LookupAccountSidW(
  LPCWSTR       lpSystemName,
  PSID          Sid,
  LPWSTR        Name,
  LPDWORD       cchName,
  LPWSTR        ReferencedDomainName,
  LPDWORD       cchReferencedDomainName,
  PSID_NAME_USE peUse
);
```

It is unicode version of  `LookupAccountSid` and `Name` is `WCHAR*`! base on [lookupaccountsidw](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-lookupaccountsidw) the `cchName` denotes the size of `Name` buffer in wchar! or count of it.

for example

```
constexpr size_t MAX_NAME = 256;

SID_NAME_USE SidType;
char lpName[MAX_NAME];
char lpDomain[MAX_NAME];
PSID pSID = NULL;     // Set real SID
DWORD dwSize = MAX_NAME;
LookupAccountSid(NULL, pSID, lpName, &dwSize, lpDomain, &dwSize, &SidType);
```